# Performance of the linear sum assignment algorithm

Tags: python, scipy, hungarian-algorithm

I have a matrix size (N,N) and I need to run the linear sum assignment algorithm on it.

I am using the scipy version of the implementation and its performance drops significantly for large matrices.

For example for N=2000 it ends up hanging for a very long time.

Here is a simple snippet which invokes the algorithm:

```
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment as linear_assignment

N = 2000
linear_assignment(10000 - np.random.rand(N,N))
```

Is there a faster implementation of the algorithm? What are typical remedies for such problems?

Thank you.

Comment: What can you tell us about the algorithm?  What is its `O(?)` running time?  I assume you've looked the the function's docs, and read up on the method it uses.

Comment: The code is in `../scipy/optimize/_hungarian.py`.  It doesn't look like it uses any specialized compiled packages.  I don't know enough of the method to know if that's significant or not.  Wiki says this scales as O(n^3), so slowing down with large N is not surprising.

Comment: So, if there is no specialized compiled package, there isn't anything to be done?

Comment: Yes, you can write your own in compiled lisp, or something like that!  Assuming this is more of a search problem than numerical array one, there probably are better tools than that found in scipy.  But you'll have to do more research.  I've never heard of this algorithm before.

Comment: The source paper for this algorithm has C# code. http://csclab.murraystate.edu/~bob.pilgrim/445/munkres.html.  I'm guessing this PYPI version is the same one that's in `scipy`, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/munkres/

Comment: I found an older question with recent updates. Follow up there.

Comment: I've added the `hungarian algorithm` tag in case you want to search for alternatives to Python.