# Create cost matrix efficiently in Python

Tags: python, loops, numpy, hungarian-algorithm

I have 2D points and I want to calculate the cost between each pair of consecutive time instances. So it's simply `norm(point 1¹ - point 2¹) + norm(point 1² - point 2²) + norm(point 1³ - point 2³)`. Please see the information below.  In C++, I would go with double for loops and it would not hurt the computation too much, but in Python... So, is there a way to do this with libraries or with just Python?

**So At time t:**

```
X_1 = [x', y'; x², y²; x³, y³]

X_2 = [x', y'; x², y²; x³, y³]

. 
.
.
```

**At time t+1:**

```
X_1 = [x', y'; x², y²; x³, y³]

X_2 = [x', y'; x², y²; x³, y³]

. 
.
.
```

I am doing this to create a cost matrix and will apply Hungarian.

Comment: Add a sample case and show us how would you implement it with double loops?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162526/performance-of-the-linear-sum-assignment-algorithm - is a recent question about calculating the humgarian-algorithm in Python.  There is a `scipy` function.  I've also ported the C# code in the MurrayState paper.  My sense is that calculating a 1000x1000 cost matrix, even with double loops, will be the fast part of the problem.  During the algorithm itself, searching for the first uncovered zero and minimum at the time sensitive tasks.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks, but my problem is creating the cost matrix. I will add an example code.