# Efficient numpy submatrix view

Tags: numpy, scipy, hungarian-algorithm

I wish to apply [Hungarian algorithm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html) to many subsets of numpy matrix `C` indexed by cross products of lists `row_ind`, `col_ind`. Currently, I see the following options to do so:

1. Double slicing:

   ```
   linear_sum_assignment(C[row_ind,:][:,col_ind])
   ```

**Problem:** two copies per subset operation.

2. Advanced slicing via [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html):

   ```
   linear_sum_assignment(C[np.ix_(row_ind, col_ind)])
   ```

**Problem:** one copy per subset, `np.ix_` is inefficient (allocates *n x n* matrix).

*UPDATE: as noted by @hpaulj, `np.ix_` doesn't it fact allocate n x n matrix, but it is somehow still slower than 1.*

3. [Masked array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/maskedarray.html).

**Problem:** doesn't work with `linear_sum_assignment`.

So, no option is satisfying.

What is ideally desired is an ability to specify a submatrix view using the matrix `C` and a couple of unidimensional masks for rows and cols respectively, so such a view could be passed to `linear_sum_assignment`. For another `linear_sum_assignment` call, I would quickly adjust masks but never modify or copy/subset the full matrix.

Is there something similar already available in numpy?

What is the most efficient way (as little copies/memory allocations as possible) to process multiple submatrices of the same big matrix?

Comment: The Hungarian algorithm will dominate this subset-preparation easily in regards to time / complexity, right?

Comment: What is `C` here? It is not entirely clear to me what the relation between `C` and the input for the Hungarian algorithm is.

Comment: More on the hungarian-algoritym and python at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162526/performance-of-the-linear-sum-assignment-algorithm (and links).  Masking creates copies, not views.  To improve significantly on the `scipy` `munkres` implementation I had to use `cython` for selected steps (especially the first-non-zero searches).

Comment: @hpaulj For all cases or something specific? For large matrices, scipy's [IPM](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.linprog-interior-point.html) should beat it (at least my IPM did; but it's different from the one used in scipy).

Comment: Initially I thought you were trying to implement `munkres` from scratch, since (as can be seen in the `scipy` code), this has a 2d cost matrix and 4 1d masking arrays.  But on further read it looks like you are working at a higher level, masking a larger matrix.  As long as `row_ind` and `col_ind` are lists or arrays, not slices, you'll be passing a copy to the `scipy` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The different ways of indexing an array with a lists/arrays time about the same.  They all produce copies, not views.

For example

```
In [99]: arr = np.ones((1000,1000),int)
In [100]: id1=np.arange(0,1000,10)
In [101]: id2=np.arange(0,1000,20)

In [105]: timeit arr[id1,:][:,id2].shape
52.5 µs ± 243 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [106]: timeit arr[np.ix_(id1,id2)].shape
66.5 µs ± 47.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

In contrast if I use slices (in this case selecting the same elements), I get a `view`, which is much faster:

```
In [107]: timeit arr[::10,::20].shape
661 ns ± 18.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

`ix_` doesn't create a (m,n) array; it returns a tuple of adjusted 1d arrays.  It's the equivalent of

```
In [108]: timeit arr[id1[:,None], id2].shape
54.5 µs ± 1.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

The timing difference is primarily due to an extra layer of function calls.

Your `scipy` link has a [source] link:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.1/scipy/optimize/_hungarian.py#L13-L107

This `optimize.linear_sum_assignment` function creates a `_Hungary` object with the `cost_matrix`.  That makes a copy, and solves the problem by searching and manipulating its values.

Using the documentation example:

```
In [110]: optimize.linear_sum_assignment(cost)
Out[110]: (array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32), array([1, 0, 2], dtype=int32))
```

What it does is create a state object:

```
In [111]: H=optimize._hungarian._Hungary(cost)
In [112]: vars(H)
Out[112]: 
{'C': array([[4, 1, 3],
        [2, 0, 5],
        [3, 2, 2]]),
 'Z0_c': 0,
 'Z0_r': 0,
 'col_uncovered': array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool),
 'marked': array([[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]),
 'path': array([[0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0]]),
 'row_uncovered': array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)}
```

It iterates,

```
In [113]: step=optimize._hungarian._step1
In [114]: while step is not None:
     ...:     step = step(H)
     ...:
```

And the resulting state is:

```
In [115]: vars(H)
Out[115]: 
{'C': array([[1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 4],
        [0, 1, 0]]),
 'Z0_c': 0,
 'Z0_r': 1,
 'col_uncovered': array([False, False, False], dtype=bool),
 'marked': array([[0, 1, 0],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1]]),
 'path': array([[1, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0]]),
 'row_uncovered': array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)}
```

The solution is pulled from the `marked` array

```
In [116]: np.where(H.marked)
Out[116]: (array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32), array([1, 0, 2], dtype=int32))
```

The total cost is the sum of these values:

```
In [122]: cost[np.where(H.marked)]
Out[122]: array([1, 2, 2])
```

But the cost from the `C` array in the final state is 0:

```
In [124]: H.C[np.where(H.marked)]
Out[124]: array([0, 0, 0])
```

So even if the submatrix that you give to `optimize.linear_sum_assignment` is a view, the search still involves a copy.  The search space and time increases significantly with the size of this cost matrix.

Comment: It is strange that `np.ix_` doesn't give any benefit compared to double slicing. I would expect that single slicing should be always faster! By any chance, do you have an idea why it is not so?