# Optimally remove rows or columns in numpy to remove missing data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, missing-data

I have a large numpy 2D array with a number of missing values (e.g. NaN), such that some rows and some columns may have multiple missing elements.

I wish to remove (or mask out) rows and/or columns to create a subset of the array, while keeping as much data as possible. The difficulty is that if I remove e.g. a row with multiple NaNs, it may negate the need to remove several columns, and vice versa.

My guess is that the optimal solution is best done iteratively, by removing e.g. the 1st row or column with at least one missing element that has the fewest non-missing values, removing it, then looking again for the next row or column with that property, etc until there are no missing values.

I suspect this is a known problem, and there may be a one-pass solution. If so, is there a name for it? Also is there a Python / numpy implementation, rather than having to roll my own?

Edit - added bonus question: I can imaging cases where it is slightly preferable to delete rows, or slightly preferable to delete columns. But of course, if (say) we prefer deleting rows, yet there is a column with all but one value missing, it would be a no-brainer to delete the column, rather than all but one of the rows. So can anyone provide a parameterised function such that for the parameter r, if r=1 we always delete rows, if r=0, we always delete columns, but for in-between values we weight row deletion and column deletion by differing relative amounts (e.g. perhaps if r=0.5 then neither column nor row deletion is preferred, and we end up maximising the amount of data retained)

Comment: Yes. The question is, whether to choose row or column first in each case

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ This seems like a very interesting problem if that is the case as if a row is removed then it effects whether or not to remove a different column or not

Comment: @JoeIddon exactly. See my added bonus question too.

Comment: Iterative usually isn't a good idea with numpy.  Operating on all rows or all columns at once is best (speed/efficiency).  It is also a good idea to identify which ones need to be removed first, and then do the removal in one action.  Removal, unless using masked arrays, actually means creating a new array without the deletes.  You don't do that in-place.

Comment: If the removal criteria is more complicated, then you need to provide an example, with expected behavior.  At first glance your problem description is too complicated, and possibly ambiguous, to provide definitive answers.  Plus most of us, when answering questions like this, do so with a test case, possibly solved in several different ways.  It's hard to give a good word solution to a word problem.

Comment: @hpaulj absolutely, I agree that I shouldn't actually remove the rows. Masking would do just as well. The reason I asked about a one-pass solution was also to avoid iteration, if possible.

Comment: @hpaulj I think the initial problem is not terribly complicated. I simply want to mask out columns and rows such as to end up with a 2D array reduced in size and with no missing data. How do I do that while minimising the number of cells that are masked out but which actually contain data. Is that ambiguous?

Comment: It's easy to count the number of NaN per row or column is easy in numpy.  But choosing the optimal mix of row/column deletes may be a search problem, which is not a numpy strong point.  I did a bit with the [tag:hungarian-algorithm] a while back, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162526/performance-of-the-linear-sum-assignment-algorithm.

Comment: @hpaulj So is this an instance of the linear sum assignment problem, or is it something else? My problem is not exactly the same, although perhaps it could be phrased in these terms. Do you think the hungarian algorithm is suited to this problem then?

Comment: I don't know for sure; it just reminds me of work I did earlier.